# Network accounts are unavailable - OS X Lion 10.7.4

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion

My OS X Lion 10.7.4 Mac is successfully binded to my MS DC. However, every time doing reboot I keep receiving "Network accounts are unavailable" with red dot color and after few seconds it goes away.

Can anyone experienced this kind of behavior and how to resolved this? I have searched around in google but no luck to get rid this annoying message.

I hope anyone would share their knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: When the computer boots it takes a moment to establish a connection with a domain controller. When the message and red dot goes away, that means the computer has successfully established a connection with the domain controller. That's life.

Comment: Thanks to your respond William. I hope apple could fix such kind of issue but I heard from others that it resolved on version 10.7.3. Later versions are facing the same problem.